# Setting up docker agents in TFS

Tags: maven, docker, tfs, tfs-2015

We are using TFS in our organisation and we manage our whole build through shell scripts (which isn't great)...

Our agent have docker installed and we run our build script inside docker. We have several images for maven, gradle, NodeJs, ...
Because of our use of Docker we cant use the maven plugin for example.

I am wondering if I can somehow benefits from the maven plugin while still running on docker?

Answer (score 1):

You could directly use [Docker Integration](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.docker) instead of managing build through shell scripts.

> The Docker extension **adds a task** that enables you to build Docker
>   images, push Docker images to an authenticated Docker registry, run
>   Docker images or execute other operations offered by the Docker CLI.
>   It also adds a Docker Compose task that enables you to build, push and
>   run multi-container Docker applications or execute other operations
>   offered by the Docker Compose CLI. Lastly, it offers a Docker Deploy
>   task that enables you to deploy single Docker images or
>   multi-container Docker applications into Azure.

Comment: Thanks. That's not solving my problem in anyway though.